# Adding Color with ng-class-even/odd

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reading [Mastering Web Development with Angular](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book), I'm trying to add colors per odd and even rows:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class-even="'blue'" 
                                         ng-class-odd="'green'">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{name: "Kevin", value: "1234"},
                   {name: "Bill", value:"444"}];
}
```

**CSS**

```
.green = {
    color: green;
}

.blue = {
    color: blue;
}
```

Yet no color shows up. This console [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector%3aunpr?p0=%24animateProvider%20%3C-%20%24animate) appears, but I'm not aware of any missing modules.

http://jsfiddle.net/r9MTc/7/

Comment: CSS... ditch them equals signs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You angular code is working fine**, problem is with your CSS. You don't need `=` sign while defining CSS class

Your CSS

```
.green = {
    color: green;
}

.blue = {
    color: blue;
}
```

Change it to

```
.green {
    color: green;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9MTc/8/)

Comment: Doh. I pulled a Homer. Thanks

Comment: @KevinMeredith, at time we all do some silly mistakes. I think its time for a coffee break

Comment: Haha, you must be thinking of something else while putting "=" :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using "=" signs. That's not how you declare CSS classes bud. Here's how:

[image]

```
.green {
    color: green;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Just switched to JavaScript recently (from Scala) :-)